# Limit number of records in MySQL table by checking criteria in other tables

Tags: mysql

I am creating a very simple database system for book rentals. I have a basic MySQL database and a PHP front-end. I'm familiar with html/css/php/js/ajax, but there is one particular piece of functionality that I can't get right.

So I have a books table and a loans table. Each book has a "quantity" attribute, and each loan has a "book name (foreign key)", "issue date", and "return date" attribute.

I'd like to prevent new loans being created for books where every copy is already on loan.

I'm not sure the best way to go about this - is it common practise to put some logic in the database itself, and monitor the number of copies on loan with an extra table or field? Or is it better to handle this kind of logic in the front-end?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities to handle this. Doing it on DB level is a good practice to make sure the data is always correct.

One option is a stored procedure that is used for laoning a book. It would check the tables and insert only if books are available. The downside is that if you don't use the procedure you have no garanties that the data is correct.

Another option would be a trigger that throws an error if one tries to insert into the loan table without any books available. To throw an error and prevent an insert you can use this line of code in your trigger:

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'insert not allowed because bla bla';
```

Another option would be using a table that holds a record for every book available and you just set the isAvailable flag in there or dates indicating if it is available or not. The structure could be like this

```
books table
-----------
id
title
author
...


book_copies table
-----------------
book_id
book_copy_number


loans table
-----------
id
book_copy_id
loan_date
return_date
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Using a stored procedure might work for this - I'm the only person likely to write or edit the front-end, so I can make sure that the procedure is always used.

What do you mean by trigger? Can I ensure a check of some kind is performed every time I try to insert data to the loan table?

For the "IsAvailable" flag - I like this idea, but it means holding mutliple copies of the same book. Let's say that I did use this idea - how do I go about selecting the "first available" copy of each book , if that makes sense?

Comment: MySQL does not support checks on table definition level. But a trigger is fired every time an insert/update is made. In there you can check things like in a procedure. Actually it is a procedure that is fired automatically.

Comment: I updated the answer. But personally I don't like the 3rd option very much. It feels to complicated.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So the best option seems to be to a procedure that is triggered on insert/udpate. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: BTW to cancel an insert/update you can use this line in a trigger: `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'insert not allowed because bla bla';`